# Running tests with karma and webpack

Tags: karma-runner, commonjs, webpack

My project has external dependecies so I configured webpack like that:

```
externals:{
        'd3':'d3',
        'another-external-dep': 'another-external-dep'
}
```

And then in the code I require the dependecies like that:

`var someProp = require('another-external-dep').someProp`.

All good until I integrated karma.
So karma when run the tests fail to find the module `another-external-dep` clearly because it is an external dependecies and I did not included in the karma config on the list of files.

How can I mock `another-external-dep` so `require('another-external-dep')` returns a mock? Also where I can specify this mock, in the config or in the mock?

Comment: What does your `karma.config.js` file look like? You should be able to include the external in the webpack property there. At least in theory, I'm trying to figure out the same thing but also having trouble.

Answer (score 8):

You can link to external dependencies during karma tests by including dependencies in the array of `files` in `karma.config.js`.

```
module.exports = function karmaConfig(config) {
    config.set({
        ...
        files: [
            'path/to/external/jquery.js',
            'tests.webpack.js',
        ],
        webpack: {
            externals: {
                'jquery': 'jQuery',
            },
        },
        ...
    });
};
```

This makes the dependencies available in the global context, which you can then reference from the webpack'd files, replicating your development context.

Comment: awesome, this directed me in the right direction for my problem +1